# How can I submit a form via POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<form id="search" action="#" method="post" style="float: left">              
    <div id="input" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" >
        <input type="text" name="search-terms" id="search-terms" placeholder="Search websites and categories..."  style="width: 300px;">
    </div>
    <div id="label" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
        <button type="submit" onclick="searchbox()" for="search-terms" id="search-label" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
    </div> 
</form>
```

When the user clicks on div id `label`, I want to toggle the display property of div `input`. which is working fine. I have used following code to implement the functionality.

```
function searchbox(){
    if ($("#input").css('display') == 'none') { 
        $('#input').css('display','block'); 
    } else { 
        $('#input').css('display','none');
    }
}
```

I want to to submit the form data via POST but that functionality is not working, neither by pressing enter key nor when submit button is clicked.

Please help me with this.

Comment: the question in the header is different to what you actually want answering

Comment: You have an action of '#' in the `<form>` tag. Is this intended?

Comment: Leter on, that '#' will be replaced with a real link of a php file, which will handle the submitted data.

I am new at stackoverflow, I wrote different header for the question, stackoverflow changed it automatically. I don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try submitting through JS

HTML

```
<form id="search" action="#" method="post">              
    <div id="input" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" >
        <input type="text" name="search-terms" id="search-terms" placeholder="Search websites and categories..."  style="width: 300px;">
    </div>
    <div id="label" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
        <button type="submit"  for="search-terms" id="search-label" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">click</button>
    </div> 
</form>
```

JS

```
$(".glyphicon").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

         if ($("#input").css('display') == 'none') { 
                $('#input').css('display','block'); 
            } else { 
                $('#input').css('display','none');
            }

            $( "#search" ).submit();

        });
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot. Also, I had to change the type of button to button.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `<input type=submit>` for submitting